# How to using onchange in type="password"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

How to using onchange in type="password" ?

first i use onchange but not work

```
<input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" OnChange="JavaScript:doCallAjax();">
```

and then i edit to use onclick it's work , how can i use onchange in ytpe="password"

```
<input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" OnClick="JavaScript:doCallAjax();">
```

What is the best way to use `onchange` with `type="password"` ?

Comment: try using onkeyup - but why are you doing ajax call everytime a letter is typed, shouldn't you do it when the form is submitted?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you thinking it should be firing after each keypress?

Comment: Tip: You can omit the `Javascript:` when setting the event handler.

Comment: `onchange` is only triggered when the control is blurred

Comment: Pete   ---  i use this code for validate form only ^^

Comment: Change works for me **[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/78Yn7/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/78Yn7/ why not work for me ?

Comment: @user3665498 works fine for me. Did you install some sort of plugin that blocks the alert? If you change it to console.log() does the line appear in the dev console?

Comment: onChange doesn't work for me in Chrome or FF.

Comment: So for both you and @alexP, shaunakde's fiddle *doesn't* work?